# how can i automatically calculate an expression from a text field

Tags: javascript, html

how can i automatically calculate an expression from a text field .. is there any function or some thing like this ..

```
 <input type="text" value="3+4" id="Txt">

    var Result = Function_in_javascript(document.getElementById("Txt").value)

    alert(Result )// 7
```

Comment: You *could* just `eval` it. Whether or not you *should* is a different issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `eval(document.getElementById("Txt").value)`

**EDIT:** What is this for though?

Comment: Just a word of warning however, while eval works, to be more secure you might want to check the input with a regex before passing it to eval.

Comment: @nmford—yes, *eval*ing arbtrary code may lead to unexpected results that may not be intended. However parsing input using a RegExp will ony be reasonable for simlpe arithmetic expressions, they can very quickly get quite complex. Note that this is no more insecure than allowing users to execute code through the address bar or developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple regex example to parse addition:

```
function parseAdditionString(s) {
  var arr = s.match(/(\d+)\+(\d+)/);
  if (arr && arr.length === 3) {
    alert("Sum = " + (Number(arr[1]) + Number(arr[2])));
  } else { alert("Invalid input"); }
}​
```

#### [See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9AmuE/)

It'll still let a lot of nonsense through, but it's better than the alternative.

**Don't use evil.**